# Converting [UInt8]? to image

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method to get an image from a server, that image I'm getting it as a byte array so I'm converting to [UInt8].

The problem is that I don't find a way to convert the [UInt8] to an Image to show in my application.

This is the code that I'm using to get the image from the server:

```
func GetSnapshotFromCamera(user: String?, password: String?, deviceNumber: String?, deviceItemId: String?) throws -> [UInt8]?{
    let url = SERVICEURL + "/GetSnapshotFromCamera/"+user! + "/" + password! + "/" + deviceNumber! + "/" + deviceItemId!
    let data = ExecuteRequestService(url)
    if(data != nil){
        let dataConverted = try ResultEventImage.ParseResultSnapshotJson(data)
        let json = NSString(data: dataConverted!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let snapshotObj = ResultEventImage.JsonToObject(json as! String)
        return snapshotObj.ResultObject
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is convert the binary array ([UInt8]) into NSData first. You can do that with:

```
let data = NSData(bytes: [UInt8], length: 2)
```

(You need to give the length of the byte array)

After converting (and unwrapping every optional) convert it to UIImage with:

```
let image = UIImage(data: data)
```

And unwrap again to get non optional image.

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to do that and see what happen, i will give you a feedback

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if let array = try GetSnapshotFromCamera(...) {
   let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: array.count)
   let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```